# SQL Server multiple tables query for a specific date from many

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables:

Table 1 - Members

```
Id   Name
1    Member1
2    Member2
```

Table 2 - Activity

```
Id   Member_id   Activity    Date
 1      1        Activity1   2001-1-1
 2      1        Activity2   2001-2-1
 3      1        Activity3   2001-3-1
 4      2        Test        2010-4-1
```

Table 3 – Detailed

```
Id  Activity_id Information
1   2       Information
```

From the following, the Member id 1 has three activities:

```
SELECT Member.id, COUNT(*) AS number
FROM Member 
INNER JOIN Activity ON Activity.Member_ID = Member.id
GROUP BY Member.id
```

My question is how I can find the id and date of the second activity (table 2) for all Members from table(1) who has 2 activities and also retrieve the information related to this activity id from table 3.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, in table `Activity` you have `Activity1` and on the table `Detailed` you have the number as the `activity_id` (2)?

Comment: do you want to group by `member` and `activity` or only `member id`?

Comment: In table Activity, the second activity_id for (activity2) is 2.  Thanks

Comment: You activity count 3 is for three different activities by member, and you cannot join that to details table and get information for only one activity.

Comment: if I group by memeber and activiy, then I will get a list of activities rather than the number of activities.  Thanks

Comment: can you show what is the desired output of the query? (actual values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row number function would help you here.

```
select *
from (
    select 
        *,
        rn = row_number() over (partition by member_id order by id)
    from
        activity
) activityWithRn
inner join detailed on detailed.activity_id = activityWithRn.id
where activityWithRn.rn = 2
```

Here I've partitioned the data by member id and the ordered the activity by its id but maybe you want to order by date?

Comment: Thank you, when I use inner join  Detailed ON Activity.id = Detailed.Activity_id.  I get this error: The multi-part identifier "Activity.id" could not be bound.

Comment: Join off the `activityWithRn` table instead of `activity`. Basically treat `activityWithRn` as your `activity` table but with the extra field `rn`

Comment: PS `partition by member_id` is optional, it acts as a grouping for each member

Comment: Thank you Mouters, this is the solution I was looking for.  It worked for (2) but not for (1) or (3) to output other activities, then I added another Member with one activity.  When I change 2 to 1, the output is empty.  If when I changed detailed on  detailed.Activity_id = Activity_id; it will list 2 rows when I enter 1, one row when changing 1 to 2 or three.  The only challenge is the information from table details does not change!  I would appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the output you're expecting, perhaps with more sample data eg with different members.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @mouters, the `ROW_NUMBER()` function is indeed helpful here. But I think the rankings should be used slightly differently than how @mouters has suggested.

Here's my attempt at a solution:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Member_id)
  FROM Activity
)
SELECT
  a.Member_id,
  number      = COUNT(*),
  Activity_id = MAX(d.Activity_id),
  Information = MAX(d.Information)
  Date        = MAX(CASE WHEN d.Id IS NOT NULL THEN a.Date)
FROM ranked a
  LEFT JOIN Detailed d ON a.Id = d.Activity_id AND a.rn = 2
GROUP BY a.Member_id
```